# Statistical method for selecting features for classification

Tags: machine-learning, data-preprocessing, feature-extraction, mnist

I'm working on a classifier for the famous MNIST handwritten data set.

I want to create a few features on my own, and I want to be able to estimate which feature might perform better before actually training the classifier. Lets say that I create the feature which calculates the ratio of ink used between two halves of a digit. Note that with ink I mean how much white there is used (which ranges from 0-255 per pixel).
[image: Example digit]

[image]

For example I would calculate the ratio between the total amount of white in the left and right halves (seperated by red line). I could also do the same with the op and bottom half, or seperate the digits diagonally. With this I can calculate the mean and standard deviation.

[image]

I imagine that the left / right ratio might give some differences for other numbers. But the ratios might all be closer to the average.

**Is there some method for estimating which feature might perform better compared to others? I.e. is there a method which gives a numerical value on how "seperable" a data set is?**